# Tell which <li> are visable Scrollbox.js

Tags: jquery

I am using scrollbox.js to create a scroller like you find on iPhone when you choose an item from a dropdown.

http://wmh.github.io/jquery-scrollbox/

I have it so that the text scrolls through properly but I would like to style them based on the position they are in the scroller.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="rollerSelector"  class="scroll-text">
      <ul>
          <li>Selection 1</span></li>
          <li>Selection 2</li>
          <li>Selection 3</li>
          <li>Selection 4</li>
          <li>Selection 5</li>
          <li>Selection 6</li>
          <li>Selection 7</li>
          <li>Selection 8</li>
          <li>Selection 9</li>
          <li></li>
      </ul>
</div>

<div id="backwardBtn"></div>
<div id="forwardBtn"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#rollerSelector').scrollbox({
    linear: true,
    delay: 0,
    speed: 60,
    autoPlay: false,
    onMouseOverPause: false,
    switchAmount: 1,
    distance: 42,
});

var myInterval = false;
$('#backwardBtn').mouseover(function(){
    $('#rollerSelector').trigger('backward');
    myInterval = setInterval(function(){
       $('#rollerSelector').trigger('backward');
    }, 1000);
}).mouseout(function() {
   clearInterval(myInterval);
   myInterval = false;
});
$('#forwardBtn').mouseover(function(){
    $('#rollerSelector').trigger('forward');
    myInterval = setInterval(function(){
       $('#rollerSelector').trigger('forward');
    }, 1000);
}).mouseout(function() {
   clearInterval(myInterval);
   myInterval = false;
});
```

I have it set so that 5 of the 10 < li > are showing and the rest are hidden. I need to style the first and second items in the list that are visible.

I tried doing something like this:

```
$("#rollerSelector li:visible:first-child").addClass("rollerFirst");
$("#rollerSelector li:visible:nth-child(2)").addClass("rollerSecond");
```

But it just always styles the first two < li > even if I have scrolled down the list and the first < li > visible is option 4

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to apply those classes to every occurring visible li elements, try using `odd/even` selectors instead of `child`.

```
$("#rollerSelector li:visible:odd").addClass("rollerFirst");
$("#rollerSelector li:visible:even").addClass("rollerSecond");
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/53m6z2ec/1/

Comment: I don't want them to show on all odd / even < li > ... There are a total of 10 < li > and 5 show at one time. I want the first < li > that is showing to have class rollerFirst and the second < li > showing to have class rollerSecond.

For example, if option 4 through option 8 are showing, option 4 would have class rollerFirst and option 5 would have class rollerSecond

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was looking at Firebug and noticed that the plugin is reordering the < li > elements.

I added the following code:

```
$('#rollerSelector li:first-child').addClass('rollerFirst');
$('#rollerSelector li:nth-child(2)').addClass('rollerSecond');
```

as part of my mouseover event. Here is the full code.

```
var myInterval = false;
$('#backwardBtn').mouseover(function(){
    $('#rollerSelector').trigger('backward');
    myInterval = setInterval(function(){
       $('#rollerSelector').trigger('backward');
    }, 1000);
}).mouseout(function() {
   clearInterval(myInterval);
   myInterval = false;
    $('#rollerSelector li:first-child').addClass('rollerFirst');
    $('#rollerSelector li:nth-child(2)').addClass('rollerSecond');
});
```

That way whenever the user stops moving the selector, it styles the new top two elements. I need to tweak the code so that it removes the classes if they are no longer in the first two spots but this is the basic idea.